# Java DateTimeFormatter

Tags: java, datetime

I am trying to read in a CSV file where I need to parse a certain date value.
However I get a DateTimeParseException I cannot place.

The field I am trying to read is a date field that looks like this:
`08-May-2016`

The code I use:
`LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(row[3], DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d-M-yy"));` where `row[3]` is the field I read from the CSV file.

The exception I get: `Text '08-May-16' could not be parsed at index 3`

Am I wrong to think that `d-M-yy` should be able to read single-digit, double-digit and letter representations for the month of the year?

EDIT: I have tried MMM-MM-M for the month as well as dd-d for the day field. I still get the same exception.

Comment: Try the pattern `"dd-MMM-yyyy"`.

Comment: @PiXel1225 I have, I still get the same exception though.

Comment: Did you read the doc: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html? Also note that month name is locale sensitive, you probably should [set a locale](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ofPattern-java.lang.String-java.util.Locale-)

Comment: @Idos, yes but still same exception

Comment: @k88 Yeah, you're right. Parsing a month in text form requires using the `LLL` representation according to [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html). So, try `dd-LLL-yyyy`.

Comment: see https://ideone.com/0z9o4x

Comment: Thanks @RC. that was indeed what was missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that you don't supply a `Locale` when you create your `DateTimeFormatter` - you need to use a `Locale` that supports that format:

```
System.out.println(LocalDate.parse("08-May-2016", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMM-yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH)));
```

Output:

```
2016-05-08
```

This doesn't work:

```
System.out.println(LocalDate.parse("08-May-2016", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-LLL-yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH)));
```

Output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '08-May-2016' could not be parsed at index 3
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:1949)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1851)
    at java.time.LocalDate.parse(LocalDate.java:400)
```

Comment: Thank you, this is the correct answer. As others have suggested, I had already tried d-MMM and dd-MMM and similar formats but that didn't work. As my pc is not set to an English datetime configuration, the lcoale was what was required.

Answer (score 2):

> Am I wrong to think that d-M-yy should be able to read single-digit, double-digit and letter representations for the month of the year?

Yes. Your pattern would parse dates of the form 1-5-16 correctly, but not 10-May-2016. Try `dd-MMM-yyyy`.